# Javascript regex to avoid word between X and Y

Tags: javascript, regex, web

I don't know much about regEx and I think I can do some pattern like the following, can I?

```
www.url.com/travels/(IwannaAvoidThis)/anotherImportantThing
```

If it's not clear: I wanna match `travels/` and `/anotherImportantThing` without caring about (IwannaAvoidThis)

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: what would you wanna match in www.url.com/travels/someThing/anotherImportantThing/somethingMore

Comment: We can't help wit unclear requirements. URLs can contain all kinds of information, so what exactly is it that you need to retrieve?

Comment: ok i think i got it and it was very basic, it may be something like:

Comment: var regEx = www.url.com/travels/?/anotherImportantThing

Comment: I think you don't need regex for this case. But it could be like this one: https://regex101.com/r/CvkOAt/2

Comment: ok thanks for that and cool website

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex capturing group and then access through index.

```js
var url = 'www.url.com/travels/(IwannaAvoidThis)/anotherImportantThing';

var result = url.match(/(travels\/).*(\/anotherImportantThing)/);
console.log(result);
console.log(result[1]);
console.log(result[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Pattern `^[^\/]+\/([^\/]+)|([^\/]+)$` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1bjGDe/1)

what you want is in Capturing groups 1&2

```
^               # Start of string/line
[^\/]           # Character not in [\/] Character Class
+               # (one or more)(greedy)
\/              # "/"
(               # Capturing Group (1)
  [^\/]         # Character not in [\/] Character Class
  +             # (one or more)(greedy)
)               # End of Capturing Group (1)
|               # OR
(               # Capturing Group (2)
  [^\/]         # Character not in [\/] Character Class
  +             # (one or more)(greedy)
)               # End of Capturing Group (2)
$               # End of string/line
```